# cannot update existing input compoent value in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a project that has a list of stuffs using ReactJS, please see [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/zatave/edit?html,output), and want to search these stuffs with keyword.

TEST: input `mi` in search box to search ID, the `this.state.data` is filtered right but **input value don't update** right(**gary** should not appear).

I've checked the problem is input component

```
<input type="text" defaultValue={this.props.data.userid} ref="userid" disabled name="userid" />
```

with **defaultValue** for the fist time render, but upcoming render don't change it's value again; But if changed it to **value**, it's cannot be edited

**Question: how to make search right also make all input editable with minimum code modify?**

Answer (score 0):

Your JSBin gives me strange output (and in a language I do not understand).
However, it looks like your problem is inside `handleChange()`, which is inside your Forms component. If you want the content of the page to update, there should be a `this.setState` function somewhere inside `handleChange`. In current setup, `handleChange()` only does console.log, but does not re-render..

Comment: `handleChange()` is for UserForm `<input>` component, it's not core part of the problem; instead of `this.setState`, there's a `this.replaceState`, which also do the rendering.

Comment: I see. React gives you basically two options to work with: you either do not render the input value, and let the form handle everything. Or, you set the value based on state or props, but in that case react requires you to define an onChange handler, to ensure that in case of changes the value is updated in the next render. If you provide a value to an input field, but NO onChange handler, then react makes the input field read-only.